# How do you texture your hard surface model

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, hard-ops

quick question to the community, I just got into hard surface modelling with hardops/boxcutter and I was wondering what approach you guys use once you have to texture your model. Do you use basic BSDF with Decalmachine? Or do you use stuff with procedural effects like materializer or Definitely Eevee Mats? Or do you unwrap your whole model to be texturized in blender nodes/Substance Painter/Quixel?

Unwrapping seems like a real paint in the butt (especially with all the booleans/bevels/Ngons,etc) and I was wondering if people encourage that approach for hard surface models.

Comment: I personally prefer to use *Shader Nodes* as it is easy to work with, in my opinion. However, if things are too complicated for me to use *Shader Nodes*, I just use the *UV* and paint in the textures.

Comment: If you plan to paint something like dirt or rust, you can unwrap with the Smart UV Project mode, you won't have to deal with the UVS anyway